# How would you fix this binary character translator?

Tags: python, binary

I'm newer to programing and am struggling to get the desired output.
My goal is to import a csv file filled with different values including A-Z,a-z, and several different special characters. I placed the row 1 and row 2 of the data into the createDictionary function to be read. My goal with the characterTranslator was to put rows 1 and 2 into an empty dictionary so I can manipulate the key/value pairs. From there I want the translator to translate any key value that's present in my given test string to into the corresponding binary value. But the binary values aren't being translated properly and I'm unsure how to fix it.

This is my code so far:

```
import csv



def createDictionary():  # opens, reads, and assigns the characters to the key and the binary to the value pairs
    # opens the file needed to work with
    with open(r"C:\Users\phill\Downloads\ASCIICharacterCodes (1).csv", "r") as data:
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        dict_from_csv = {rows[1]: rows[0]for rows in reader}
        return(dict_from_csv)

def characterTranslator():
    translated_dictionary = {}
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        translator = ''.join(bin(ord(c)) for c in value).replace('b', '')
        translated_dictionary[key] = translator
        return translated_dictionary


print("before translation")
mydict = createDictionary()

#print(mydict)

print("\n\nAfter translation")
mapping = characterTranslator()




sentence = "Hello World! Welcome to 'programing' world :)"
file = open("output.txt",'w')
for ch in sentence:
    if(ch in mapping.keys()):
        file.write(ch + " " + str(mapping[ch]) + "\n")
    else:
        file.write(ch + " " + "UNKNOWN" + "\n")
file.close()
```

OUTPUT:

```
H UNKNOWN
e UNKNOWN
l UNKNOWN
l UNKNOWN
o UNKNOWN
  UNKNOWN
W UNKNOWN
o UNKNOWN
r UNKNOWN
l UNKNOWN
d UNKNOWN
! UNKNOWN
  UNKNOWN
W UNKNOWN
e UNKNOWN
l UNKNOWN
c UNKNOWN
o UNKNOWN
m UNKNOWN
e UNKNOWN
  UNKNOWN
t UNKNOWN
o UNKNOWN
  UNKNOWN
' UNKNOWN
p UNKNOWN
r UNKNOWN
o UNKNOWN
g UNKNOWN
r UNKNOWN
a UNKNOWN
m UNKNOWN
i UNKNOWN
n UNKNOWN
g UNKNOWN
' UNKNOWN
  UNKNOWN
w UNKNOWN
o UNKNOWN
r UNKNOWN
l UNKNOWN
d UNKNOWN
  UNKNOWN
: UNKNOWN
) UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Hello, you shouldn't be posting screenshots of your code because other people would have to retype the code over again, which may take them a lot of time. You can also find out [how to post a good, minimal, and reproducible example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that your question could be answered even faster.

Comment: What is your exact problem? You posted an image of some code, but it's unclear what you're stuck on? Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Hi Grismar, I apologize this is my first post. The problem is when I translate my test string, the binary values that correspond to the key/value pair aren't returning. Next to each letter in the output should be the corresponding binary value.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a solution to the problem you posted but just deleted. The reason that you are getting the `UNKNOWN` output is because your if statement is passing to the else clause. You need to rewrite the if statement to `if ch in mapping.keys():` for this to work. However, I can't verify that this alone would fix the issue as I don't have the .csv file you have.

There is an easier way to do what you are trying to do. Simply use `ord(ch)` to get the decimal of the character (as you already were), and test if it is 127 or below. If so, it is an ASCII character. The code below outlines this.

```
sentence = "Hello World! Welcome to 'programming' world :)"
with open("output.txt", 'w') as f:
  # Output sentence
  output_str = "{0} {1:b}\n"
  for ch in sentence:
    char_no = ord(ch)
    if char_no <= 127:
      # Character is ASCII, write binary value
      f.write(output_str.format(ch, char_no))
    else:
      # Character is not ASCII
      f.write(ch + " UNKNOWN\n")
```